# take a screenshot and visually highlight the focused control

Tags: forms, controls, screenshot, documentation-generation, interprocess

After happily using open source software for many years I've figured it's time to give back. And since documentation is usually a weak point for many projects, plus my C# skills are not exactly in high demand in my corner of FLOSS land, I've figured I'll start with tutorials, etc.

After the second tutorial for a burning tool, I already got annoyed with the routine of

1. take screenshot
2. highlight any important part
3. annotate it
4. add to website
5. repeat

and figured I could automate that.

I guess what I'm looking for is a program that would take a screenshot of the currently open window, paint e.g. a yellow bar around the focused control (a button maybe) then pop up a little textbox for me to enter a description for the picture and finally add it all to a website/database/list/etc.

Now for my actual question: Unless anybody knows a tool that already does that, I need some starters on how to access size and position of controls on 'foreign' windows so that I can  calculate where to paint those highlighting bars around important controls. I remember those password-unmasking tools for Windows that could reveal the content of any `******`-protected textbox, but I can't find any open examples on that.. WinAPI stuff I guess, WindowFromPoint + GetDlgItem or something like that. No idea if it's any easier in Linux, either one will be fine though. No preference on programming language either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my knowledge, what you want to do requires some P/Invoke, since .NET does not feature any API for accessing the windows of other applications.

You could probably start by using [GetForegroundWindow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633505.aspx) to get the current Window (you would need to fire that code using a global hotkey or a timer, because if you switch windows to take the screenshot, you will get your own window returned from GetForegroundWindow).

## Edit

I got inspired by your question to do a little Sunday afternoon coding. I found out, that GetForegroundWindow will get you the foreground Window, but not a Control level. But there is another useful function, [GetGUIThreadInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633506.aspx), that will get you the currently focused control and some other info. We can use [GetWindowInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms633516.aspx) to get the information about the Window (which might be a control contained in a top-level window).

Putting these things together, we can make a Window class that abstracts away all the gritty P/Invoke calls:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;

namespace dr.Stackoverflow.ScreenshotTest
{
    public class Window
    {
        private WINDOWINFO info;
        private readonly IntPtr handle;

        internal Window(IntPtr handle)
        {
            this.handle = handle;
        }

        public int Handle
        {
            get { return handle.ToInt32(); }
        }

        // Note - will not work on controls in other processes.
        public string Text
        {
            get
            {
                int length = GetWindowTextLength(handle);
                if ( length > 0 )
                {
                    StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder(length);
                    if (0 < GetWindowText(handle, buffer, length))
                    {
                        return buffer.ToString();
                    }
                }
                return "<unknown>";
            }
        }

        public Rectangle WindowArea
        {
            get
            {
                EnsureWindowInfo();
                return info.rcWindow;
            }
        }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return String.Format("{0} 0x{1}", Text, handle.ToString("x8"));
        }

        private unsafe void EnsureWindowInfo()
        {
            if (info.cbSize == 0)
            {
                info.cbSize = sizeof (WINDOWINFO);
                if ( !GetWindowInfo(handle, out info) ) 
                    throw new ApplicationException("Unable to get Window Info");

            }
        }

        public static Window GetForeground()
        {
            IntPtr handle = GetForegroundWindow();
            if (handle == IntPtr.Zero)
                return null;

            return new Window(handle);
        }

        public unsafe static Window GetFocus()
        {
            IntPtr foreground = GetForegroundWindow();
            int procId;
            int tId = GetWindowThreadProcessId(foreground, out procId);
            if (0 != tId)
            {
                GUITHREADINFO threadInfo = new GUITHREADINFO() {cbSize = sizeof (GUITHREADINFO)};
                if ( GetGUIThreadInfo(tId, out threadInfo) )
                {
                    return new Window(threadInfo.hwndFocus);
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        private struct WINDOWINFO
        {
            public int cbSize;
            public RECT rcWindow;
            public RECT rcClient;
            public int dwStyle;
            public int dwExStyle;
            public int dwWindowStatus;
            public uint cxWindowBorders;
            public uint cyWindowBorders;
            public int atomWindowType;
            public int wCreatorVersion;
        } 

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        private struct GUITHREADINFO
        {

            public int cbSize;
            public int flags;
            public IntPtr hwndActive;
            public IntPtr hwndFocus;
            public IntPtr hwndCapture;
            public IntPtr hwndMenuOwner;
            public IntPtr hwndMoveSize;
            public IntPtr hwndCaret;
            public RECT rcCaret;
        }

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        private struct RECT
        {
            public int left;
            public int top;
            public int right;
            public int bottom;

            public static implicit operator Rectangle(RECT rhs)
            {
                return new Rectangle(rhs.left, rhs.top, rhs.right - rhs.left, rhs.bottom - rhs.top);
            }
        }

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern bool GetWindowInfo(IntPtr hwnd, out WINDOWINFO pwi);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern int GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr handle, out int processId);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, ExactSpelling = true)]
        private static extern bool GetGUIThreadInfo(int threadId, out GUITHREADINFO threadInfo);

        [DllImport("user32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, ExactSpelling = true)]
        private static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();

        [DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError = true, CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
        private static extern int GetWindowTextLength(IntPtr hWnd);

        [DllImport("user32", CharSet = CharSet.Auto, SetLastError = true)]
        private static extern int GetWindowText(IntPtr hWnd, [Out, MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPTStr)] StringBuilder lpString, int nMaxCount);
    }
}
```

Then we can make a sample program using it:

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Imaging;
using System.Threading;

namespace dr.Stackoverflow.ScreenshotTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Sleeping for 3 seconds (switch to a window of interest)");
            Thread.Sleep(3000);

            Window currentWindow = Window.GetForeground();
            Window focusedWindow = Window.GetFocus();       
            if ( currentWindow != null )
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Foreground window");
                Console.WriteLine(currentWindow.Text);
                Console.WriteLine(currentWindow.WindowArea);
            }
            if (focusedWindow != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\tFocused window");
                Console.WriteLine("\t{0}", focusedWindow.WindowArea);
            }

            if (focusedWindow !=null && currentWindow != null && focusedWindow.Handle != currentWindow.Handle)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\nTaking a screenshot");
                Rectangle screenshotArea = currentWindow.WindowArea;
                Bitmap bm = new Bitmap(currentWindow.WindowArea.Width,currentWindow.WindowArea.Height);
                using(Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bm))
                {
                    g.CopyFromScreen(screenshotArea.Left,screenshotArea.Top, 0,0, new Size(screenshotArea.Width,screenshotArea.Height));
                    Rectangle focusBox = focusedWindow.WindowArea;
                    focusBox.Offset(screenshotArea.Left * -1, screenshotArea.Top * -1);
                    focusBox.Inflate(5,5);
                    g.DrawRectangle(Pens.Red,focusBox);
                }
                bm.Save("D:\\screenshot.png", ImageFormat.Png);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This will make a screenshot of the current foreground window with a red box highlighting the currently focused control. Please be aware that this is sample code and features minimal error-checking :-) When you run it, Alt-Tab to the window of interest and stay there until the program finishes.

There are some limitations though. The most important one i discovered is that this approach won't work in a WPF application - simply because the individual controls is not Windows, as they are in other Windows programs.

Comment: Wow.. Marry me?
That is pretty much exactly what I had in mind, and it's even my beloved C# - thank you very much :)